# .htaccess how to see variables collected from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

`.htaccess` has the ability to collect lots of information.

For example, `REQUEST_FILENAME` `REMOTE_ADDR` `REQUEST_URI`

How do I output the information I collected so I can see and learn what these variables store?  I host with GoDaddy and don't have access to the actual server.

- Is there a way to create any type of log file so that I can see the information I'm collecting?
- If that's not possible is there a way to spit the small piece I collected back into the address bar so I can see it?
- Is there some other creative solution to see the small pieces of info I'm collecting?

Answer (score 1):

For testing purpose, you could create a php file in your root with the following :

```
<?php
echo "The get variable is $_GET['val']";
?>
```

And put the following to your htaccess

```
RewriteEnginge on
RewriteRule ^help/?$ /file.php?val=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will internally forword **site.com/help** to **/file.php** with the variable you are testing.

Comment: Thanks so much but dang the PHP throws an error.  `syntax error, unexpected quoted-string and whitespace`

Comment: I removed the `''` around val and it stopped throwing the error in my editor.  After I uploaded both files and ran then them I still get an internal server error, `Internal Server Error  The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`  I know I have to be close but it's not quite working.

Comment: @DR01D Perhaps mod-rewrite isnt enabled on your server.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled.  I've never used val= but other than that I understand your code. ^help/?$ takes the word help, with or without a / and rewrites it as /file.php(variable I'm looking for) and then stops rewriting with the [L].  That's a brilliant idea but something must be just a bit off.  But I don't know enough to spot the problem.